# Any elegant method to build relation between string and integer in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class which has many fields of the type String. I want to write a method as a setter for all these fields, so I need a switch. Here comes my question, how to map the field name into an integer to be fit in switch? I don't want `Integer.parseInt()`, because I don't know what char may be and couldn't choose a appropriate radix. I don't want to manually build a map neither. Is there any handy trick?

Comment: is coding a handy trick?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use strings in switch case itself? You don't need to use make any relation between string and integer for that. Java 7 maintains this internally.

```
switch(string){
case "one":
  -- do something--
  break;
case "two":
  -- do something --
  break;
....
..
```

And if you really want to maintain a nice and effective relation between string and integer so that you can use that in switch - **have a look in the implementation of switch using string - and check its byte code**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List which will have setter and getter. List can hold any kind of Object.

```
List<Employee>  empList = new ArrayList(Employee);

    public List<Employee> getEmpList() {
            return empList;
        }


        public void setEmpList(List<Employee> empList) {
            this.empList = empList;
        }

In your Employee Class 

Employee
String firstName
String lastName
String address
int age
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do what everybody else does and encode the field name into the method name instead of a parameter:

```
public void setXXX(int xxx) // sets XXX
public void setYYY(int yyy) // sets YYY
```

Comment: Not just setter, I want use it as a uniform modify interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an enum where the members are named exactly as your input strings:

```
enum MyEnum { CASE_1, CASE_2 }
```

Then you can simply switch on `MyEnum.valueOf(inputString)`:

```
switch (MyEnum.valueOf(inputString)) {
  case CASE_1: setCase1Field(); break;
  case CASE_2: setCase2Field(); break;
}
```